# reCAPTCHA suddenly stopped working for about an hour in seminar room

Tags: recaptcha

I'm giving some training courses this week, each for 15 people, on how to handle a rather complex web form and the corresponding administration tool. At the end of the form there is a Google reCAPTCHA. It always worked until today, be it during the courses, my personal tests and a one-month test phase with ~50 participants.
In the training course today from 9AM to 12AM it worked, it still worked during my presentation on the second course at around 4PM. But when I asked the participants to fill out the form it didn't show up. I couldn't find any error messages, it just wasn't displaying any more. Luckily, I had a Plan B, but this was bugging me.
The 15 computers in the seminar room all operate under the same public IP address. Could it be that Google temporarily flagged the room's IP address as a potential threat because there were a lot of CAPTCHA requests coming from a single IP address?
I checked via my mobile phone (connected to my mobile provider) and there the captcha was showing correctly. About one and a half hours later, the CAPTCHA worked again in the seminar room.

Any ideas on what happened there? I don't want this to happen again tomorrow and I'm thinking about deactivating the CAPTCHA for the duration of the courses.

The systems in the room are Win7 with latest updates. The installed browser is IE11.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds to me more like a network issue on your side.

Comment: I would also consider deactivating the captcha.  Perhaps I would make a video showing how it works (wouldn't be a long video), or, like you did before, pull it up on your phone or another device not connected to the network.  At the same time, if I was being trained on how to use a form that doesn't work, I would be considering my other options.

Comment: Yes, that's my opinion as well. Was a bit embarrassing, unfortunately I'm not in control of the seminar room, this is a completely other company providing it (to be precise it's the seminar buildingowned by a city in Germany). Could very likely be a problem with their inrastructure, there are some other "odd" things happening there. Should have a chat with their IT.

Comment: Sometimes when recaptcha determines that user is already verified, it does not present user any recaptcha. You can confirm this by calling `grecaptcha.getResponse()` api on browser console log. If it returns a non-zero length string token, it means recaptcha thinks user is verified human and wont show the challenge.